# Private embedded struct when importing a struct from another package

Tags: go, encapsulation, embedding

I have a project which relies on a struct imported from another package, which I will call `TheirEntity`.

In the example below, I (ahem) embed `TheirEntity` in `MyEntity`, which is an extension of `TheirEntity`, with added functionality.

However, I don't want to export `TheirEntity` in the `MyEntity` structure, as I would rather the consumer not access `TheirEntity` directly.

I know that Go embedding is not the same as inheritance in classical OOP, so maybe this is not the correct approach, but is it possible to specify embedded structs as "private", even if they are imported from another package? How might one achieve the same thing in a more idiomatic fashion?

```
// TheirEntity contains functionality I would like to use...

type TheirEntity struct {
    name string
}

func (t TheirEntity) PrintName() {
    fmt.Println(t.name)
}

func NewTheirEntity(name string) *TheirEntity {
    return &TheirEntity{name: name}
}

// ... by embedding in MyEntity

type MyEntity struct {
    *TheirEntity // However, I don't want to expose 
                 // TheirEntity directly. How to embed this
                 // without exporting and not changing this
                 // to a named field?

    color        string
}

func (m MyEntity) PrintFavoriteColor() {
    fmt.Println(m.color)
}

func NewMyEntity(name string, color string) *MyEntity {
    return &MyEntity{
        TheirEntity: NewTheirEntity(name),
        color:       color,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [I]s it possible to specify embedded structs as "private", even if they are imported from another package?

No.

> How might one achieve the same thing in a more idiomatic fashion?

By not-embedding but making it a unexported named field.

Comment: I suspected as much. The downside to the named field is that, in this scenario, I have to implement several functions in `MyEntity` as part of a contract to several interfaces that `TheirEntity` implements. Embedding allows me to satisfy that contract without having to reimplement.

Answer (score 16):

Since the question was asked, Go [1.9](https://go.dev/doc/go1.9) saw the addition of [*type aliases*](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Alias_declarations) to the language. Through an unconventional use of type aliases, you can actually have your cake and eat it too!

First, declare an unexported alias for the third-party type you wish to embed in your struct:

```golang
type theirEntity = TheirEntity
```

Then, simply embed that alias instead of the original type:

```golang
type MyEntity struct {
    *theirEntity
    color string
}
```

([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/rauhpKyo1mQ))

Comment: What is the difference to embed with a private name?

Comment: @ceving I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking how my approach improves upon simply embedding `TheirEntity`? If you do that, `TheirEntity` becomes an exported field of `MyEntity`, which may be undesirable. The OP explains this well in his question.

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
type MyEntity struct {
    *privateTheirEntity
}

type privateTheirEntity struct {
    *TheirEntity
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).